# AutoFixture + NSubstitute + Virtual methods

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture, nsubstitute

Wanting to know if there's a way to mock a virtual method on a concrete class using AutoFixture and NSubstitute. I've been able to do this easily with Moq, as can be seen here:

```
public class SomeConcreteClass
{
    public string MethodA()
    {
        return MethodB();
    }

    public virtual string MethodB()
    {
        return "AAA";
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SomeConcreteClassTests
{
    private IFixture _fixture;
    private SomeConcreteClass _someConcreteClass;

    [SetUp]
    protected void Setup()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var someConcreteClassMock = _fixture.Create<Mock<SomeConcreteClass>>();
        _someConcreteClass = someConcreteClassMock.Object;
        someConcreteClassMock.CallBase = true;
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeScenario()
    {
        Mock.Get(_someConcreteClass).Setup(m => m.MethodB()).Returns("BBB");
        var actual = _someConcreteClass.MethodA();
        actual.ShouldBe("BBB");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best achieved if you use AutoFixture's support for [Parametrised Tests](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html), here illustrated using [xUnit.net](https://xunit.github.io) (but, IIRC, there's similar support for NUnit):

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void ImplicitSubtituteViaAttribute([Substitute]SomeConcreteClass scc)
{
    scc.MethodB().Returns("BBB");
    var actual = scc.MethodB();
    Assert.Equal("BBB", actual);
}
```

Using the `[Substitute]` attribute enables you to explicitly tell AutoFixture that, although you asked for a concrete class, it should create it via NSubstitute so that you can override any virtual members it might have.

`AutoNSubstituteData` is defined like this:

```
public class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute() :
        base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

`AutoDataAttribute` comes from [AutoFixture.Xunit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2), but if you prefer NUnit over xUnit.net, you should be able to use [AutoFixture.NUnit3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.NUnit3) instead.

---

Otherwise, I'm not sure you can achieve exactly the same result as with AutoFixture.AutoMoq. In this degenerate example, you can do this:

```
[Fact]
public void ImperativeWorkaround()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
    fixture.Register(() => Substitute.For<SomeConcreteClass>());
    var scc = fixture.Create<SomeConcreteClass>();
    scc.MethodB().Returns("BBB");

    var actual = scc.MethodB();

    Assert.Equal("BBB", actual);
}
```

This is, however, fairly pointless, as you could just as well have written this:

```
[Fact]
public void Reduction()
{
    var scc = Substitute.For<SomeConcreteClass>();
    scc.MethodB().Returns("BBB");

    var actual = scc.MethodB();

    Assert.Equal("BBB", actual);
}
```

In other words, AutoFixture doesn't actually *do* anything in that workaround.

I could imagine that the real issue is that in real usage, the concrete class in question has other members or constructor data that you wish to fill with data. The problem is that due to the way NSubstitute is designed, I'm not aware of any way you can declaratively ask for a 'substitute'; you'll have to use the `Substitute.For` method, which then completely short-circuits AutoFixture's ability to hook into the process and add its own behaviour.

With Moq, this is possible because in the OP, you're not asking AutoFixture for a `SomeConcreteClass` object, but rather for a `Mock<SomeConcreteClass>`, and that enables AutoFixture to distinguish.

In other words, Moq follows the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020) that *explicit is better than implicit,* and that makes it extensible to a degree not easily achieved with NSubstitute. For that reason, I've always considered Moq to have the better API.

Comment: Thanks so much Mark, I really appreciate that. Yes, I love that AutoFixture allows me to not have to worry about what args the constructor requires or the order thereof. Huge fan of yours by the way, and enjoyed your talks on Pluralsight.